# Efficient method for np.dot computation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Is there a time-efficient way to do so? Because the dimension is huge (4096), this snippet is taking a lot of time.

```
for j in multiple_img_features:
        img_feature = j
        t = np.zeros((1,4096))
        for i in range(len(vectors)):
            t = t + np.dot(vectors[i],img_feature)
```

I need to compute [image: This] where phi is the image features and alphas are the eigen vectors. The DImension of alphas is (100,4096) and for a single image is (4096,)

In the code, multiple_img_features correspond to a set of image features of dimension (10,4096) Each single row corresponds to a vector of 4096 features of a single image. vectors are the alphas (100,4096)

Comment: If you provide more and specific details, you'll get quicker help, like - objective, sample data and approx time required to run the loop.

Comment: `np.dot` is efficient.  But give us an idea of the shapes of variables.  Better yet, provide both the big shapes, and a small example that we can test improvements on.  `@`, `np.matmul` can do 'batches' of `dot` products.

Comment: added a few more details

Comment: Something like `vectors @ multiple_img_features.T`  should  solve your problem without Python loops. Probably, you will need additionally to get a sum along some axis.